# importing celery in project fails, works(sort of) in manage.py shell

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

Im going over this list here but i cant get it working :

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html

So what i did was:
1) downloaded celery modules and added them to my manage.py and wsgi.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os, sys
from ConfigParser import RawConfigParser

config = RawConfigParser()
abspath = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

config.read(abspath+'/subfolder/settings.ini')

homedir = config.get('paths', 'libspath')
projectspath = config.get('paths', 'projectspath')

path = [
    '/Django-1.4.5/', 
    '/South-0.7.6',
    '/python-openid-master',#07.05.2013 checkout from https://github.com/openid/python-openid
    '/mbi-django-rosetta-eca151e',
    '/phonenumbers-5.2b1',
    '/django-phonenumber-field-develop',
    '/django-openid-auth-0.5',
    '/celery-3.0.19',
    '/django-celery-3.0.17',
    '/kombu-2.5.11',
    '/billiard-2.7.3.28',
    '/anyjson-0.3.3',
    '/amqp-1.0.12'
    ]

for item in path:
    module = homedir+item
    if module not in sys.path:
        sys.path.append(module)
```

2) installed rabbitmq
3) set up stuff in settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ---
    'djcelery',
)
```

and in the end:

```
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/'
import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()
```

4) ran python manage.py syncdb

5) since im using mod_wsgi i also added this to my wsgi.py (in addition to code i showed earlier)

```
import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()
```

6) i created tasks.py in my core app:

```
import logging, subprocess
logger = logging.getLogger('debugger')

from django.conf import settings

from celery import task

@task
def runfunc(funcname, refno):
    x = 'nothing to see here'
```

7) i run: python manage.py celery worker --loglevel=info
and get whole bunch of stuff meaning that its all good :P.

But when i go the django view which is supposed to run the task i get:

```
cannot import name task
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost/url/that/triggers/task/
Django Version: 1.4.5
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
cannot import name task
Exception Location: /path/to/project/core/tasks.py in <module>, line 6
```

When i go to manage.py shell and type
from celery import task - it works just fine.
if i import the function from core.tasks, then i get exactly same error message.

Can anyone explain to me wth is up here..

Alan

Comment: Is the django view really running through django? ie. is it not a static page? Is the settings module loaded there? (`from django.conf import settings`)

Comment: yes it is running through django and settings module is also loaded there.

Comment: If you look at point 6) - you can see that settings is loaded there.

Comment: Yes, I see but that is in the tasks module. Is it also loaded in the view? I am not familliar with celery-as-django-app so it may be an automatic view..

Comment: Can you also print 'abspath' and 'sys.path' from your manage.py in the run-from-manage and in the run-from-view case? I suspect you have some python path problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try altering tasks.py to:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from celery import task
```

It's possible that you have a `celery/` or `celery.py` in the same directory as the module throwing the error (`tasks.py`), and this is failing as a relative import.

Comment: This indeed fixes it. After checking the folder and project in my head for folders and files for celery (and finding nothing), i remembered that i first created file named celery.py that i later renamed to tasks.py for exactly the same reason. But i forgot to delete .pyc file. Which caused all this mess :/

Answer (score 1):

Yikes, where did you get all that in your first step?? I've never had to alter the `manage.py` or `wsgi.py` files to get additional packages running. You say "downloaded celery modules" and then you have all that `sys.path` alteration code. That leads me to believe you aren't using `pip` and `virtualenv`. Your life will be massively easier using those two tools. You'll simplify things so much your team will love you forever. Don't over-complicate when Python package management exists to make this pain free. Path mangling is rarely necessary.

Those [Celery first steps](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html) you reference are really all it takes. Looks like you've handled that special `mod_wsgi` note. My guess is the problem lies in the first step -- whatever modifications you've made to manage.py and wsgi.py. All the other steps look fine*.

I'd make a copy of your code, make a new virtualenv, pip install those packages and remove all the path setup stuff. Use `django-admin.py startproject xxx` to see what plain vanilla `manage.py` and `wsgi.py` files look like. Also use `DEBUG=True` to help with the troubleshooting. When that works and you get things settled, replace your `settings.ini` with a pip [requirements file](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/requirements.html).

* You use South so remember `python manage.py migrate djcelery`. (In your step 4 you only use `syncdb`). I don't believe doing this will fix the import error but it's necessary in the larger picture.

Comment: The first part looks a bit like a buildout type of generated file. I certainly hope it is...

Comment: Nope. not using neither pip nor virtualenv. I found that its much easyer to update manage.py & wsgi.py than to update (or create new) virtualenvironments just to test different versions of some django modules/snippets. so instead of versioned files i would have different virtualenvironments stacking up.